# How to run script on AWS through Jenkins build

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am new to Jenkins and AWS. I have a MongoDB scripts on AWS EC2 instance. The first script need to run before the jenkins build and stores the snippets of DB. Second script need to run post build to restore to that snippets. Scripts are done ready to be used. I just couldn't find a exact way to get to AWS through build and implement this in a Jenkins job. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins [stages](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#stage) to to the Prebuild operation, Build and then Post build operations. With the stages you can use a plugin like [SSH Pipeline Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) to remotely execute commands on your EC2 instance.